# How to convert my folder into application using C# .net 2.0?

Tags: c#, iis

I am having my project(folder format) in IIS, i want to convert that folder into application (like right click->Convert to application), i want to perform this in C# code, i am using .net 2.0. i followed this link [Using ServerManager to create Application within Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518186/using-servermanager-to-create-application-within-application/15815005#15815005), but i don't know

```
Site site = serverManager.Sites.First(s => s.Id == 3);
```

What is that? when i try to add that code i am getting error called:     **microsoft.web.administration.sitecollection does not contain a definition for first**

Please do some replies...

Comment: Have you included Microsoft.Web.Administration in your page?

Comment: yes i added Microsoft.Web.Administration as a reference to my project and added as namespace in my page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is that?

It's [`LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) and it is not available in .NET 2.0. You will need to use .NET 3.5 or later and have the `System.Core` assembly referenced in your project and the `System.Linq` namespace added to your `using` directive in order to bring the [`.First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) extension method into scope.

If you cannot upgrade to a more recent version of .NET you could achieve similar results with the following:

```
Site site = null;
foreach (var s in serverManager.Sites)
{
    if (s.Id == 3)
    {
        site = s;
        break;
    }
}
if (site == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements that match the criteria (Site Id = 3)");
}

// at this stage you could use the site variable.
```

Comment: I want to use .net 2.0 to achieve this task, i don't want .net 3.5 to proceed, can i get any other samples to achieve this task in .net 2.0?

Comment: Sure, you could search the Sites collection for the element that matches your criteria. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i can convert to application, when i try to browse that application "HTTP Error 403.18 - Forbidden
The specified request cannot be processed in the application pool that is configured for this resource on the Web server." i am getting this error what will be the problem?