# How to exclude a particular folder from ASP.NET 6 on IIS and allow it to process by PHP handlers?

Tags: php, asp.net-core, iis

I can deploy an ASP.NET 6 web app to IIS on Windows 2019 Server.
All is working.

The default web.config is generated and exist in the root:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath=".\TestWebApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
</system.webServer>
```

**Question**

I would like to have a /blog folder and I would like deploy a PHP application there.
How can I explain to IIS to not pass those request to the AspNetCoreModuleV2 handler, instead pass those requests to the PHP handler? (url rewrite module is already installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended using the `<location...>` element and removing the handler from the blog path.

The key is removing the handler for the blog subfolder, which can be done with the `<remove>`. It is possible either with using the `<location...>` element, or as an alternative placing a web.config to the blog subfolder, and removing the handler there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\TestWebApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="blog">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can create a `Virtual Application` under your webapp site.***

The official documentation has only one paragraph describing this Virtual Application. The answers in the following posts are very detailed and will help you.

[Using ServerManager to create Application within Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526489/7687666)

**My Test Result for you**

This test in the azure web app, it's same as IIS.

[How to deploy a Flask+React application to Azure Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63985149/7687666)